# How to put single quatation for values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put value inside quatation in javascript but not working.I am getting datas values from service and i am trying to change the values with single quatation.I do not know how to do it.

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3tj28p?file=index.js

```
var datas="sd1,sd2,sd3,sd4";
```

output should be

```
console.log(datas)// 'sd1','sd2','sd3','sd4'
```

Please help..How to do it?

Comment: If you cannot alter the original string, have a go at the [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [the Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) functions!

Comment: What will single quote do which double quotes cannot do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var datas="sd1,sd2,sd3,sd4";

var str = datas.split(",").map((item)=>{
  return `'${item}'`;
}).join(",");

console.log(str);
```

```js
var datas="sd1,sd2,sd3,sd4";
var str = datas.split(",").reduce((acc,cur,index) => {
  if(index === datas.split(",").length-1){
    return acc+=`'${cur}'`;
  }
  return acc+=`'${cur}',`;
},"");
console.log(str);
```

```js
var datas="sd1,sd2,sd3,sd4";


var arr = datas.split(",");
var str = "";
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  str+=`'${arr[i]}'`;
  if(i !== arr.length-1) str+=`,`
};
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Super..But can you use any other method instead of map?

Comment: @VimalaK I added another way with `reduce()`.

Comment: @VimalaK I also added another way with `for-loop`

Comment: @VimalaK what's wrong with `map` ? perfectly fine solution

Answer (score 0):

- You split the `datas` string by `,` you will have `['sd1','sd2','sd3','sd4']`
- Map through each item and add `''` to them, you will have `["'sd1'","'sd2'","'sd3'","'sd4'"]`
- Join them back, you will get `'sd1','sd2','sd3','sd4'`

```js
var datas="sd1,sd2,sd3,sd4";
let dataArr = datas.split(",")
dataArr = dataArr.map(item => `'${item}'`)
datas = dataArr.join()
```

Comment: Please understand my question..i can not edit datas